# Phone camera still active after startActivityForResult with Camera intent

Tags: java, android

I took picture by opening the phone camera using camera intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileProvider);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

It worked fine, I got the photo so taken. The problem is that after a while, even when the application is not in focus, I get a notification that the Camera is idle.

What could be the cause? The Camera doesn't close
[image]

Comment: What device are you using? Are yout reproduced the issue at different devices?

Comment: The device is Infinix X557 running Android 7.0. Well, I haven't tried the application on other devices but hoping to do so later today.